# Courses / Events and Registrations App Bug

Tags: 2sxc

I have the same problem with a new system and it is a very old bug.
Registration fail.
https://github.com/2sic/app-events-and-courses/issues/1
I am looking for a workaround.

Thanks Thomas

I tried three diffrent systems but no success.

```
var course = AsDynamic(App.Data["Course"].List[Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["cid"])]);
```

> Error: System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005):
>   d:\home\site\wwwroot\Portals\43\2sxc\Courses_Course-Registration.cshtml(12):
>   error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult
>   result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String
>   cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode,
>   Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is some very old code - because the List object changed in 2017. So first of all let's get you going:

Read this blog - it tells you what changed and how to fix it: https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/fixing-the-breaking-change-in-2sxc-9-8-list-instead-of-dictionary

Since you installed a new system (that's what I understand), could you point me to where you got the code - so I can have the original fixed?

Comment: I installed the app in th the actual release(https://2sxc.org/Portals/0/adam/AppCatalog/FDiKIqf26keBxP-WZMXf6Q/Download/2sxcApp_CoursesandRegistrations_03.00.00.zip) and found the same code in https://github.com/2sic/app-events-and-courses/blob/master/_Course-Registration.cshtml . It seams it is the actual code and I find your hint: "This app used a very internal interface (IEntity) which was moved in 2sxc 9, so we chose to re-publish it." Is there republished another an newer App? Sorry I didn't find it.

Comment: We completely rebuilt the app from scratch to make it more consistent with the use cases, but it was never quite finished (documentation etc.) so it's been unpublished for half a year or so. if you are interested (it is way better), pls mail me on info 2sxc org and we'll discuss it there.